# csv file converted to parquet adds 'e0' to end of values

Tags: pandas, amazon-redshift

I am running a test to populate a table in Redshift. I added mock data to a csv file and then converted to parquet with pandas. I'm using the COPY command to get the data from the parquet file in the s3 bucket to my Redshift database.

I got the error:

```
    'file has an incompatible Parquet schema for column'
```

Those columns are DECIMAL (12,3).
I checked in the s3 console and found that in looking at my converted parquet file, 'e0' had been added to the end of values, example:

```
    {"id":2873130000000000000,"field1":9.335e0,"field2":9.335e0}
```

My code to convert to parquet is standard:

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
    df.to_parquet('test.parquet')
```

At this point it seems these added values are why I'm getting that 'incompatiblity' error. Why would these values be added, how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are writing the parquet file with these fields in scientific notation.  This is where e stands for 'times ten to the power of' eg. 1.1e2 equals 110.  Check your formatting pandas.